# How to persist date data in given timezone

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When using Hibernate only application using property like `hibernate.jdbc.time_zone` helps me to save all date formats in my desired timezone example UTC.

How to achieve the same using spring boot jpa with minimal or no code change?
Is there some property to add in application.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application.properties you can specify Hibernate properties by prefixing them with spring.jpa.properties. like this:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding hibernate as your jpa implementation, then you can define provider specific settings in configuration file.

Comment: spring boot jpa uses internally Hibernate and I am looking easier way to define them like in application.properties with minimum or no code change

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Jackson timezone for deserialization via this configuration:

```
spring.jackson.time-zone=UTC
```